# R merge three dataframe without forming the cartesian product

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have the following dataframes a,b,c

```
Year<-rep(c("2002","2003"),1)
Crop<-c("TTT","RRR")
a<-data.frame(Year,Crop)

Year<-rep(c("2002","2003"),2)
ProductB<-c("A","A","B","B")
b<-data.frame(Year,ProductB)

Year<-rep(c("2002","2003"),3)
Location<-c("XX","XX","YY","YY","ZZ","ZZ")
c<-data.frame(Year,Location)
```

and want to get them together. When I use the `merge` function i get the cartesian product which is not what I want.

```
d<-merge(a,b,by="Year")
e<-merge(d,c,by="Year")
```

I would like the dataframe to look like

```
Year   Crop    ProductB    Location
 2002  TTT      A              XX
 2002   NA      B              YY
 2002   NA      NA             ZZ
 2003  RRR      A              XX 
 2003   NA      B              YY
 2003   NA      NA             ZZ
```

Is this possible? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using `data.table`.

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
# (1)
setDT(a)[, GRP := 1:.N, by=Year]
setDT(b)[, GRP := 1:.N, by=Year]
setDT(c)[, GRP := 1:.N, by=Year]
# (2)
merge(a, merge(b, c, by=c("Year", "GRP"), 
          all=TRUE), by=c("Year", "GRP"), all=TRUE)

#    Year GRP Crop ProductB Location
# 1: 2002   1  TTT        A       XX
# 2: 2002   2   NA        B       YY
# 3: 2002   3   NA       NA       ZZ
# 4: 2003   1  RRR        A       XX
# 5: 2003   2   NA        B       YY
# 6: 2003   3   NA       NA       ZZ
```

> - (1) - `setDT` converts the `data.frame` to `data.table` and then we create a new column `GRP` by grouping by `Year`. With this, we've a unique combination of `Year, Grp`.
> - (2) - we merge on the two columns `Year, GRP`.

`.N` is an inbuilt variable that holds the number of rows for that group.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. I think I understood the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Arun's answer will output what you want with your toy example. I'll just add two comments.

First. You're not getting the cartesian product. That would be accomplished by setting `by = NULL`, Compare the outputs of the following lines:

```
merge(a, b, by = "Year")
merge(a, b, by = NULL)
```

Second. I see how your desired output is constructed. But I don't see the logic behind it. How am I (or the algorithm) to know that e.g. `TTT` is to be matched up to `A` and `XX` and not, say, `NA` and `ZZ`? Why is `B`only matched to `YY`and not `ZZ`, say?

EDIT: By the way, Arun's strategy also works with the `merge` function without the `data.table` package.

```
a$Grp <- seq_len(nrow(a))
b$Grp <- seq_len(nrow(b))
c$Grp <- seq_len(nrow(c))

d <- merge(a, b, by = c("Year", "Grp"), all = TRUE)
e <- merge(d, c, by = c("Year", "Grp"), all = TRUE)
e[,-2]
```

Comment: Thanks AEBilgrau for pointing at the issue with the logic. The point is that the matching does not matter. It is just about rearranging data coming from different data sources and combine them to one table that is passed to knitr/Latex. The table should show which events took place in a particular year, the order does not matter.